# Please help finishing the calculation to prove that ” Pareto distribution & Power distribution has inverse relationship”.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Let X follows Pareto distribution with parameters α,  a,   h.

that is X~Pa(α,a,h)

Where,   α>0  is the shape parameter,    -∞< a <∞   is the location parameter,   h>0 is the scale parameter.

So the pdf of X is : p(x) = (α*h^ α)/(x-a)^( α+1) ;   x≥a+h

Let Y follows Power distribution with parameters α,  a,   h.

that is Y~Po(α,a,h)

Where,   α>0  is the shape parameter,    -∞< a <∞   is the location parameter,   h>0 is the scale parameter.

So the pdf of Y is : p(y) = α*h^(- α) *(y-a)^( α-1) ;   a≤y≤a+h

For proving the relationship that Pareto distribution & Power distribution has inverse relationship   I have followed the procedure that

I will consider  X= 1/V  where X~Pa(α,a,h)

Then if the pdf of V is same as the pdf of Power distribution then I will conclude that  ” Pareto distribution & Power distribution has inverse relationship”.

So,
X~Pa(α,a,h)

the pdf of X is : p(x) = (α*h^ α)/(x-a)^( α+1) ;   x≥a+h

let , X= 1/V

the Jacobian of transformation is |J| = |dx/dv| = |-1/v^2| = 1/v^2

hence the pdf of V is:

p(v) = (1/v^2) * (α*h^ α)/{(1/v)-a}^( α+1) ;     v≥{1/(a+h)}

=> p(v) = v^(-2) * (α*h^ α)/ [{(1-va}/v]^( α+1)

=> p(v) = {v^(-2) * (α*h^ α) * v^( α+1) }/ (1-va)^( α+1)

=> p(v) = { α* h^ α * v^( α-1) } / (1-va)^( α+1)

Then I am not understanding how to proceed so that the result will be :

p(v) = α*h^(- α) *(v-a)^( α-1) ;   a≤v≤a+h    with the limit